# not going into the for loop

Tags: loops, if-statement, vbscript

I have two arrays and I need to compare their values. I wrote a `for` loop and when I am trying to debug it's not going into the loop at all.

```
Dim i, value
Dim flag
i = 0
For i = 0 To UBound(groupName_LocationsTable) - 1
    flag = False
    If groupName_LocationsTable(0, i) = groupName_getLocationsAPI(0, i) Then
        flag = True
    End If
Next 
If flag Then
    Response.Write groupName_LocationsTable(i) & " not found<br />" "Pass"
Else
    Response.Write groupName_LocationsTable(i) & " not found<br />"
End If
```

Comment: Try adding `Option Explicit` to the top if script, then you’ll see what isn’t defined. Where is the `groupName_LocationsTable` and `groupName_getLocationsAPI` defined? Just posting some arbitrary code with no context and expecting us to tell you why your code doesn’t work is ridiculous. Consider reviewing [ask] and how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hint: If your code isn’t going into the loop, check the value of `UBound(groupName_LocationsTable) -1`. You might be checking the wrong upper bound of the array, especially if it contains multiple dimensions. By default `UBound()` will check the first dimension.

Answer (score 3):

You mix Size (number of items) and UBound (last valid index) of an array. To loop over all elements you need to access `a(UBound(a))`:

```
Option Explicit

Dim a : a = Array("one and only")
WScript.Echo TypeName(a), UBound(a), a(0)
Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    WScript.Echo i, a(i)
Next
WScript.Echo "now you don't"
For i = 0 To UBound(a) - 1
    WScript.Echo "UBound <> Size"
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 47043861.vbs
Variant() 0 one and only
0 one and only
now you don't
```

Comment: You're right about the -1 on `UBound()` but I still think you've completely ignored the fact they're using a multi-dimensional array *(like from `GetRows()`)* which means the dimension they're checking for the size of the array is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the multi-dimensional arrays *(like in memory recordset retrieved from `GetRows()`)* you have likely forgotten to explicitly check the second dimension of the array when using the `UBound()` function.

```
'Check the second dimensions upper bound.
For i = 0 To UBound(groupName_LocationsTable, 2)
    flag = False
    If groupName_LocationsTable(0,i) = groupName_getLocationsAPI(0,i) Then
        flag = True
    End If
Next
```

Have removed the `If` statement at the end because you can’t just switch from single to multi-dimensional arrays. If you are going to output the array values you would need to specify both dimensions.

It’s also worth noting your `flag = True` won’t work as you expect but I'm not going into that now. To be honest, the approach needs to be re-worked.